# fastest way to create a list from a numpy array of lists

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of lists.  this is of type numpy.ndarray:

```
   array([list([2692, 2711]), list([2751, 2770]), list([3455, 3462]),
   list([4020, 4027]), list([7707, 7726]), list([7893, 7912]),
   list([8118, 8126]), list([8174, 8179]), list([8215, 8234]),
   list([9227, 9246]), list([9518, 9537]), list([9839, 9859]),
   list([10002, 10021]), list([10024, 10043]), list([10158, 10178]),
   list([11346, 11365])], dtype=object)
```

I want to create a list from the first element of each sublist.  I'm doing it by a list comprehension:

```
 lst = [ x[1] for x in m ]
```

Is there a quicker way to create this list?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> m[:, 0]
array([2692, 2751, 3455, 4020, 7707, 7893, 8118, 8174, 8215, 9227, 9518,
       9839, 10002, 10024, 10158, 11346], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I tried that.  It works with type numpy.array but gives an error with type numpy.ndarray.  IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: I created an ndarray `m` by copying exactly the list you posted. The type of `m` is ndarray. All numpy arrays are stored as ndarrays. So this indexing should work on any 2 dimensional ndarray. I can edit my answer to include the construction code as well?

Comment: I manually created this array and it works as you mentioned.  For some reason I'm getting an error when I extract this array from a larger numpy matrix converted from a panda dataframe.

Comment: You can't recreate the 1d object dtype array with a copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a rather significant speedup by using `m.tolist()` instead of `m`. For an additional minor saving use `zip`:

```
[*zip(*m.tolist()).__next__()]
# [2692, 2751, 3455, 4020, 7707, 7893, 8118, 8174, 8215, 9227, 9518, 9839, 10002, 10024, 10158, 11346]
```

Comment: how can I create a list of the second element in each list?

Comment: @afshin For that your list comprehension applied to `m.tolist()` is hard to beat.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is 1-d array of list objects, so directly slicing on axis 1 as `m[:, 0]` will fail because it has no axis 1. If every sub-list has the different lengths, I can't think of any better solution than list comprehension. However, if every sub-list has the same length(as in your sample every sub-list has length of 2), you may use `np.vstack` to convert it to 2-d array and slice as follows

```
n = np.vstack(m)[:,0].tolist()

Out[371]:
[2692,
 2751,
 3455,
 4020,
 7707,
 7893,
 8118,
 8174,
 8215,
 9227,
 9518,
 9839,
 10002,
 10024,
 10158,
 11346]
```

Comment: I do need it back as a numpy array, so I tried n = np.vstack(m[:,0]   It was slower than my list comprehension above

Comment: Numpy arrays provides simple and convenient way to slice elements on the whole axis. However, on mixed object types, converting those sub-lists to numpy array costing time.  If time is crucial, I think your best solution in this case is list comprehension as you say.

Comment: Another solution using numpy is  `np.array(m.tolist())[:,1]`. This solution is faster than `np.vstack`, but It is still slower than list comprehension for your data